# How to convert ConfigurationSection to object?

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-service-fabric

I have a service fabric .net microservice.  I'm trying to access values in my settings.xml file.  I would like to convert a configuration section to a strongly typed object.

I don't want to have to retrieve one value at a time if able.

```
var config = FabricRuntime.GetActivationContext()?.GetConfigurationPackageObject("Config");

// Is something like below already available?
KeyVaultOptions kvOptions = pkg.Settings.Sections["KeyVault"] as KeyVaultOptions
```

Answer (score 0):

The returned object is of type `ConfigurationSection`, you can't directly cast that into an instance of type `KeyVaultOptions`. You could create a cast [operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/conversions#103-explicit-conversions) for that, or use a [mapper](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Getting-started.html).